# Output buffering - Echo values dynamically?

Tags: php

I want to echo string dynamically, not all of them at once when script finished running. Tried this one, but it echos all of them when script finished running. How can I echo values dynamically ?

```
<?php
ob_start();

echo "Line #1...<br>";
ob_flush();
flush();
sleep(2);

echo "Line #2...<br>";
ob_flush();
flush();
sleep(2);

echo "Line #4...<br>";

?>
```

Comment: are you sure that it isn't your browser buffering before display?

Comment: As pointed by Jon Taylor, the browser is doing its own buffering. So I don't think it is achievable using only PHP.

Comment: Tip: you also might want to change the [execution time](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) of your script if it'll take longer then 30seconds

Comment: Some browsers would like to render the page after the full document has loaded. Especially for XHTML

Answer (score 2):

Try sending a line-ending like \n or append at least 256 spaces to each echo to trigger the browser.

Some browsers will wait for at least 256bytes before rendering, others need a newline char. Try this combination before each flush:

```
echo str_repeat(" ", 256) . "\n";
```

Other cause could be the webserver that is caching the response.

Comment: isn't it 512 for html5 now? Or am I confusing this with something else?

Comment: I think it more depends on browser implementation then on the html version.

Comment: It works only if I use
echo str_repeat("sent", 256) . "\n";
And it echos "sent" 256 times dramatically. How to fix that ?

Comment: Increase the number of spaces. Use 1024 instead of 256